# Robot Framework: is there a better way to test items in a menu?

Tags: automation, robotframework

I'm writing a test to verify a web menu has all the required items, so I created a keyword called "Verify Menu" with several items like this:

```
Verify Menu
  Wait Until Element Is Visible     ${menu}
  Page Should Contain Element       ${home menu item}
  Element Text Should Be            ${home menu item}  Home
  Page Should Contain Element       ${products menu item}
  Element Text Should Be            ${products menu item}  Products
  Page Should Contain Element       ${brands menu item}
  Element Text Should Be            ${brands menu item}  Brands
  Page Should Contain Element       ${find us menu item}
  Element Text Should Be            ${find us menu item}  Find us
  Page Should Contain Element       ${our history menu item}
  Element Text Should Be            ${our history menu item}  Our History
  Page Should Contain Element       ${contact us menu item}
  Element Text Should Be            ${contact us menu item}  Contact Us
```

I know this is a keyword implementation and not part of a test itself, however, it looks a bit messy to me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the `Wait Until Element Is Visible` is there to determine the page has fully loaded. Then the subsequent combinations of `Page Should Contain Element` and `Element Text Should Be` are there to verify the element.

Personally I think the `Page Should Contain Element` is included in the `Element Text Should Be` as well. It will fail and provide a similar message.

That said, if you want to keep the duo, but do away with the extra lines of code, then opt for a custom keyword:

```
Verify Menu
  Wait Until Element Is Visible     ${menu}
  Validate Element            ${home menu item}  Home
  Validate Element            ${products menu item}  Products
  Validate Element            ${brands menu item}  Brands
  Validate Element            ${find us menu item}  Find us
  Validate Element            ${our history menu item}  Our History
  Validate Element            ${contact us menu item}  Contact Us

*** Keywords ***
Validate Element
    [Arguments]    ${identifier}    ${value}
    Page Should Contain Element       ${identifier}
    Element Text Should Be            ${identifier}    ${value}
```